# How do I get to be a ringside professional at wrestling promotions?

Tags: professional, event

I'm very keen on approaching Indy wrestling promotions to be at ringside with my 60d and taking shots of their events.

Having not taken any shots professionally before, I find I'm at a loss at how to approach the show runners to actually ask them if I can be ringside.

1. Would I need to prepare a release or copyright statement stating that the photographs I take are not for sale via my website or anything like that?
2. Or at least broach the matter of asking if they would like to use my shots to pay for them?

I intend in paying the ususal ticket price for entry and not necessarily going into this initially as a "hire me", as I have no prior shots from such events because of my quandry.

I would really appreciate the feedback and experiences of photographers who have been or are involved with Indy promotions

Comment: Your statement of not selling your photographs seems directly at odds with "professional". Is selling your images (or time) your eventual goal?

Comment: Yeah that is the eventual goal, but without having some shots of wrestling promotions under my belt already, I can't really sell myself as a wrestling photographer. I appreciate my question may be a bit convoluted, but the key question is what's the best way to approach them and is a copyright doc. recommended?

Answer (score 1):

just approach them and ask if you can take some shots for your portfolio.  Tell them in return you'll give them copies of all the shots for their own use.

Where you may run into trouble is being right outside the ring can be a dangerous place.  you really need an insiders understanding of what's going on to know how to stay out of the way if you're going to be ring side.  You may think you're lined up for the perfect shot but that's when the wrestler comes over the top rope and lands right on your camera snapping the lens right off the mount, giving you a black eye and severely cutting the wrestler.

This would not be a good scenario.

Comment: That could bring up the topic of insurance and risk assessments.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've already considered this and already need public liability for the day job. I've attended shows before, generally no dq/hardcore matches so I'm well aware of the potential risk. A very good point to raise for anyone else though! /\

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is that you need to be able to offer the organisers something they want. Simply asking to have a ringside seat to take photos isn't going to cut it considering any old Tom Dick and Harry could just do the same.

What will they get out of it? Well considering they will have other professional photographers already there who have the equipment and experience to take these kind of pictures I expect you will need to think of something else, unless of course they are blown away by your previous work.

I would try contacting one of the other photographers to see if they would like some extra help but again that would depend on your equipment (usually needs to be very fast focussing for sports) and experience as a photographer in general.

I can kind of see this going in the same direction as most photographers starting out and that classic question "how can I get experience?" the answer unfortunately is usually start small and work your way up.

Comment: I do have an angle for getting my foot in the door which coincides nicely with the photography. I already have a range of lenses, the only one near suitable for this though would be the EF 85mm f/1.8. The only other alternative would be to rent a lense.

The promotions in my region are generally well lit, so that's one bonus

Comment: The main problem is that you're using a very basic camera for sports photography and I can't see it being able to focus properly. I suppose the only way to find out is to ask, but like I said you will probably need to give them a good reason.